# setting global variables in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, global-variables

I have been searching the internet for hours but have yet to figure out what I am doing wrong.
I have created a login form, which has a combobox for user name and a text box for the password.
I need to save the user name for future use, so I have created a new module and in it a global variable for the name:

> Option Compare Database
>
> Option Explicit
>
> Public Name As String

I am trying to set a value in a private sub into this variable like this:

> Name = Me.cmbClient.Value

but i keep getting this error "run-time error '2135': this property is read-only and can't be set"
I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I would really appreciate it if someone could help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Name is a reserved word in VBA.

Comment: omg, thank you so much! I have literally been pulling my hair not realizing what the problem was! You are a life saver!!!!